# Android Fatal Signal 11 in FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Hi am using Ffmpeg library for Video Streaming in Android app.I have done compilation and import successfully.When i execute the app the video plays 2 secs and after that it crashes.can anyone give me the solution.

Here is the logcat :

```
09-07 12:41:06.108    1826-1826/com.ffmpegtest W/linker﹕ libffmpeg-neon.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.   
09-07 12:41:07.178    1826-1904/com.ffmpegtest A/libc﹕ invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x75ad1f98 passed to dlfree
09-07 12:41:07.178    1826-1904/com.ffmpegtest A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 1904 (AsyncTask #1)
```